# Java 8, jfxrt.jar not included?

Tags: software-installation, java

Just got my Pi yesterday, and I've been trying to install Java for use with a Java/JavaFX application. I keep getting a classNotFound exception in my app when I try to run it. It turns out, there's no jfxrt.jar in my Java installation. I installed the Linux/Arm hard float from the Oracle website several times and none of them seem to include it. Isn't jfx included in Java 8? Am I going wrongly somewhere?

(Using Rasbian)

Comment: I see this file under "JDK8u5\jre\lib\ext", and since it's a JAR file and java is portable, I don't see any particular reason why you couldn't copy it from elsewhere (i.e. non-arm version) and place it there (but make sure to grab it from an equivalent version.. perhaps your java 8 isn't update 5 like mine)

Comment: Make sure you're using the java you think you are with `java -version`.

Comment: 1.8.0_06 is the version it gave me. Good idea to check.

Comment: Oh, and would getting jfxrt.jar from another location work? It isn't patform specific right? Just the Java and javac are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the media portion of JavaFX is not supported on Arm devices. Would've been nice if they'd mentioned that on the java-arm download page.